# Drupal AEgir hosting system and cPanel

Tags: drupal

I am working on some Drupal websites.
The Drupal websites are managed by AEgir hosting system.

Can AEgir get into the file folder to add/edit the Drupal files there?

AEgir is something like cPanel? Looks not.

If it is not like cPanel.
So I still need to get Control Panel from web hosting company?

I mainly need to get into the file, code, database... SHELL / FTP into the server machine.

Answer (score 0):

From the AEgir project:
*"A Drupal based hosting frontend or control panel for managing your entire network of websites."*

But also: [Can Aegir be installed next to CPanel/Plesk/AlternC/etc?](http://community.aegirproject.org/faq#Can_Aegir_be_installed_next_to_CPanelPleskAlternCetc) **The anwer is No**!

Check the [AEgir Distribution page](https://drupal.org/project/hostmaster) and the [AEgir Handbook](http://community.aegirproject.org/handbook).

You may probably need to find the '**hostmaster Drupal profile**', which will use to manage all of the sites you host.

There are also some [Contrib Modules](http://community.aegirproject.org/contrib-modules) for more tasks.

Hope that helped!